# Python on Alpine with pt_BR locale still outputs in english

Tags: python, docker, locale, alpine-linux

I have a docker running on `python:3.6-alpine`, and I used [this](https://gist.github.com/Herz3h/0ffc2198cb63949a20ef61c1d2086cc0) to make the locale goes to `pt_BR`.
The problem is that my `LocaleHTMLCalendar` does not display my output in Portuguese on docker (if I run on my machine, it works).

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine as BUILD
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates wget && \
    wget https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/2.25-r0/glibc-2.25-r0.apk && \
    wget https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/2.25-r0/glibc-bin-2.25-r0.apk && \
    wget https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/2.25-r0/glibc-i18n-2.25-r0.apk && \
    apk add --allow-untrusted glibc-bin-2.25-r0.apk glibc-i18n-2.25-r0.apk glibc-2.25-r0.apk

COPY ./locale.md /locale.md
RUN cat locale.md | xargs -i /usr/glibc-compat/bin/localedef -i {} -f UTF-8 {}.UTF-8
ENV LANG=pt_BR.UTF-8 \
    LANGUAGE=pt_BR.UTF-8 \
    LC_ALL=pt_BR.UTF-8
COPY . /app/
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["./start.sh"]
```

So if I run this on my docker:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.getlocale()
('pt_BR', 'UTF-8')
>>> import calendar
>>> x = calendar.LocaleHTMLCalendar()
>>> x.formatmonth(2019,2)
'<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="month">\n<tr><th colspan="7" class="month">February 2019</th></tr>\n<tr><th class="mon">Mon</th><th class="tue">Tue</th><th class="wed">Wed</th><th class="thu">Thu</th><th class="fri">Fri</th><th class="sat">Sat</th><th class="sun">Sun</th></tr>\n<tr><td class="noday">&nbsp;</td><td class="noday">&nbsp;</td><td class="noday">&nbsp;</td><td class="noday">&nbsp;</td><td class="fri">1</td><td class="sat">2</td><td class="sun">3</td></tr>\n<tr><td class="mon">4</td><td class="tue">5</td><td class="wed">6</td><td class="thu">7</td><td class="fri">8</td><td class="sat">9</td><td class="sun">10</td></tr>\n<tr><td class="mon">11</td><td class="tue">12</td><td class="wed">13</td><td class="thu">14</td><td class="fri">15</td><td class="sat">16</td><td class="sun">17</td></tr>\n<tr><td class="mon">18</td><td class="tue">19</td><td class="wed">20</td><td class="thu">21</td><td class="fri">22</td><td class="sat">23</td><td class="sun">24</td></tr>\n<tr><td class="mon">25</td><td class="tue">26</td><td class="wed">27</td><td class="thu">28</td><td class="noday">&nbsp;</td><td class="noday">&nbsp;</td><td class="noday">&nbsp;</td></tr>\n</table>\n'
```

You can see my ouput is in English instead of Portuguese.

Any idea of what am I missing?

**EDIT**

Here is my docker run command:
`docker run  --env LANG=pt_BR.UTF-8 --env LANGUAGE=pt_BR.UTF-8 --env LC_ALL=pt_BR.UTF-8 --env LC_TIME=pt_BR.UTF-8  -p 8000:8000 myapp:locale`

Comment: It looks like a bug in Python [locale.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/locale.py#L560). This function docstring is inconsistent with what it is actually doing, and it doesn't use any other env vars than LANGUAGE. Can you try calling this function inside the container and check the returned values?

Comment: as a workaround, you can pass explicitly pass the locale: `x = calendar.LocaleHTMLCalendar(locale='pt_BR')` (btw, internally it is using `LC_TIME` for locale)

Comment: I tried an ENV called LC_TIME, and `x = calendar.LocaleHTMLCalendar(locale='pt_BR')`, neither worked

Comment: I added my docker run command. @Marat which function do u want me to run inside the container?